# Replace where with having

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a group by - having query ,
Can I add additional where conditions to having clause instead of adding extra where clause.Will the result be same?Will there be any case when all of where could not be added to a having clause.
I require this since I am working on a query generation tool , and this specific feature will save me some work on UI and query generation logic.

eg

```
USE AdventureWorks ;
GO
SELECT SalesOrderID, SUM(LineTotal) AS SubTotal
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
GROUP BY SalesOrderID
HAVING SUM(LineTotal) > 100000.00 and  SalesOrderID>43875 and SalesOrderID <46066
ORDER BY SalesOrderID
```

and

```
USE AdventureWorks ;
GO
SELECT SalesOrderID, SUM(LineTotal) AS SubTotal
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
where  SalesOrderID>43875 and SalesOrderID <46066
GROUP BY SalesOrderID
HAVING SUM(LineTotal) > 100000.00 
ORDER BY SalesOrderID
```

Comment: In general you put aggregate function conditions in the HAVING clause, and regular conditions in the WHERE clause. If you keep following that rule you'll never go wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The results will be the same if the columns referenced are in the `group by` clause.

However, putting them in the `where` clause is advantageous, because SQL Server can eliminate rows *before* doing the aggregation.  This is usually more efficient than removing them afterwards.  It is possible that SQL Server has an optimization for this that I'm not familiar with.

You cannot add conditions to the `having` clause if they involve columns that are not in the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE is used to filter/condition the result set before you run GROUP BY.

HAVING is used to filter/condition the result set after you have grouped.

So while in some situations you can get the same result - the two operators aren't the same and don't do the same, so you should use the proper operator for what you're trying to achieve.